# Encryption by repeatedly squaring key and flipping source bits?

Tags: encryption

I came up with a simple way to encrypt a series of bits and I cannot seem to find a weakness. I know almost nothing about cryptography so I was wondering if someone could help me out and find the fault in this method. It is incredibly simple, so I'm almost definitely not the first one to try this out, but I couldn't find anything like it online.

Method:

Given are a sufficiently long key and a stream of input bits.

1. If the last bit of the key is a 1, then flip the current bit in the input stream.
2. If the last bit of the key is a 0, then don't do anything.
3. Square the key and truncate it so that it still fits within whatever key size is desired.
4. Repeat.

This would yield an encrypted stream of output bits.
Executing the same process on an encrypted message would yield the decrypted message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reviewing custom ciphers is [off-topic](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/should-we-allow-questions-about-amateur-ciphers) here. But a word of recommendation: you yourself say you know almost nothing about cryptography. You should be using established ciphers rather than making your own.

Comment: It's trivially not CPA secure. Query any message. Now we can tell from the correct whether the last bit will be flipped out not. Then just output messages with differing last bits for the challenge.

Comment: Squaring the key cuts security down to almost nothing. Imagine you have a number XXX2, where Xs are just any number. The square of this number *will always* be X..X4. and the square of that will be X...X8, and the square of that will be X...X6, etc etc. I'm saying X..X because you don't know how many digits there will be, but they don't matter if you only look at the last bit. I the same thing happens on the binary level, and this cypher becomes an XOR with a 1010101010101010 bitstream - the only element of randomness is starting bit, so it'll be trivial to brute force, there's only 2 keys.

Comment: @CarsonGraham That keystream doesn't seem right. If your interpretation of the question is correct (that squaring takes place over the integers and not some other structure and that the "last" bit is the least significant bit, none of which are really clear) The keystream is either all zeroes, if the original key is even and all ones if the original key is odd.

Comment: As noted, we are asked to review a cryptographic design, which is off-topic. Plus this is XOR of the input stream with a keystream dependent only on the key, thus trivially vulnerable to a single known plaintext. In addition, there are several possible interpretations of "truncate".